# Внутри слайдера Coda Slider jQuery скрипт исполняется два раза

Tags: jquery, xml, slider

Вот код:

```
/***********************************************************************
*
*  Coda Slider 3
*  Kevin Batdorf
*
*  http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider
*
*  GPL license & MIT license
*
 ************************************************************************/

// Utility for creating objects in older browsers
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
Object.create = function( obj ) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = obj;
    return new F();
};
}

(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
var Slider = {
    //initialize
    init: function( options, elem ) {
        var self = this;

        //remove no JavaScript warning
        $("body").removeClass("coda-slider-no-js");

        //add preloader class (backwards compatible)
        $('.coda-slider').prepend('<p class="loading">Loading...<br /><img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" alt="loading..." /></p>');

        // Cache the element
        self.elem = elem;
        self.$elem = $( elem );

        // Cache the ID and class. This allows for multiple instances with any ID name supplied
        self.sliderId = '#' + ( self.$elem ).attr('id');

        // Set the options
        self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.codaSlider.options, options );

        // Cache the ID and class. This allows for multiple instances with any ID name supplied
        self.sliderId = '#' + ( self.$elem ).attr('id');

        // Build the tabs and navigation
        self.build();

        // Start auto slider
        if (self.options.autoSlide) {self.autoSlide();}

        self.events();

        // Test the preloader (image doesn't load)
        //alert("Testing preloader");

        // Kill the preloader
        $("p.loading").remove();

    },
    build: function() {
        var self = this;

        // Wrap the entire slider (backwards compatible)
        if ( $(self.sliderId).parent().attr('class') != 'coda-slider-wrapper' ) {$(self.sliderId).wrap('<div id="' + ( self.$elem ).attr('id') + '-wrapper" class="coda-slider-wrapper"></div>'); }

        // Add the .panel class to the individual panels (backwards compatable)
        $(self.sliderId + " > div").addClass('panel');
        self.panelClass = self.sliderId + ' .panel';
        // Wrap all panels in a div, and wrap inner content in a div (backwards compatible)
        $(self.panelClass).wrapAll('<div class="panel-container"></div>');
        if ( $(self.panelClass).children().attr('class') != 'panel-wrapper' ) { $(self.panelClass).wrapInner('<div class="panel-wrapper"></div>'); }
        self.panelContainer = ($(self.panelClass).parent());

        // Store hash Links
        if (self.options.hashLinking) {
            self.hash = (window.location.hash);
            self.hashPanel = (self.hash).replace('#', '');
        }

        // Store current tab
        self.currentTab = (self.options.hashLinking && self.hash) ? self.hashPanel - 1 : self.options.firstPanelToLoad - 1;

        // Apply starting height to the container
        if (self.options.autoHeight) { $(self.sliderId).css('height', $($(self.panelContainer).children()[self.currentTab]).height() + $(self.sliderId + '-wrapper .coda-nav-right').height()); }

        // Build navigation tabs
        if (self.options.dynamicTabs) { self.addNavigation(); }

        // Build navigation arrows
        if (self.options.dynamicArrows) { self.addArrows(); }

        // Create a container width to allow for a smooth float right.
        self.totalSliderWidth = $(self.sliderId).outerWidth(true) + $($(self.sliderId).parent()).children('[class^=coda-nav-left]').outerWidth(true) + $($(self.sliderId).parent()).children('[class^=coda-nav-right]').outerWidth(true);
        $($(self.sliderId).parent()).css('width', self.totalSliderWidth);

        // Align navigation tabs
        if (self.options.dynamicTabs) { self.alignNavigation(); }

        // Clone panels if continuous is enabled
        if (self.options.continuous) {
            $(self.panelContainer).prepend($(self.panelContainer).children().last().clone());
            $(self.panelContainer).append($(self.panelContainer).children().eq(1).clone());
        }

        // Allow the slider to be clicked
        self.clickable = true;

        // Count the number of panels and get the combined width
        self.panelCount = $(self.panelClass).length;
        self.panelWidth = $(self.panelClass).outerWidth();
        self.totalWidth = self.panelCount * self.panelWidth;

        // Variable for the % sign if needed (responsive), otherwise px
        self.pSign = 'px';

        self.slideWidth = $(self.sliderId).width();

        // Puts the margin at the starting point with no animation. Made for both continuous and firstPanelToLoad features.
        // ~~(self.options.continuous) will equal 1 if true, otherwise 0
        $(self.panelContainer).css('margin-left', ( -self.slideWidth * ~~(self.options.continuous)) + (-self.slideWidth * self.currentTab) );

        // Configure the current tab
        self.setCurrent(self.currentTab);

        // Apply the width to the panel container
        $(self.sliderId + ' .panel-container').css('width', self.totalWidth);

    },

    addNavigation: function(){
        var self = this;
        // The id is assigned here to allow for the responsive setting
        var dynamicTabs = '<div class="coda-nav"><ul></ul></div>';

        // Add basic frame
        if (self.options.dynamicTabsPosition === 'bottom') { $(self.sliderId).after(dynamicTabs); }
        else{ $(self.sliderId).before(dynamicTabs); }

        // Add labels
        $.each(
            (self.$elem).find(self.options.panelTitleSelector), function(n) {
                $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('.coda-nav ul').append('<li class="tab' + (n+1) + '"><a href="#' + (n+1) + '" title="' + $(this).text() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
            }
        );
    },

    alignNavigation: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.totalNavWidth = 0;
        var arrow = '';

        if (self.options.dynamicArrowsGraphical) {arrow = '-arrow';}

        // Set the alignment
        if (self.options.dynamicTabsAlign != 'center') {
            $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('.coda-nav ul').css(
                'margin-' + self.options.dynamicTabsAlign,
                // Finds the width of the arrows and the margin
                    $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find(
                        '.coda-nav-' +
                        self.options.dynamicTabsAlign +
                        arrow
                    ).outerWidth(true) + parseInt($(self.sliderId).css('margin-'+ self.options.dynamicTabsAlign), 10)
            );
            $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('.coda-nav ul').css('float', self.options.dynamicTabsAlign); // couldn't combine this .css() with the previous??
        }
        else {
            // Get total width of the navigation tabs and center it
            $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('.coda-nav li a').each(function(){self.totalNavWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true); });
            if ($.browser.msie) { self.totalNavWidth = self.totalNavWidth + (5);} // Simple IE fix
            $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('.coda-nav ul').css('width', self.totalNavWidth + 1);
        }
    },

    addArrows: function(){
        var self = this;
        $(self.sliderId).parent().addClass("arrows");
        if(self.options.dynamicArrowsGraphical){
            $(self.sliderId).before('<div class="coda-nav-left-arrow" data-dir="prev" title="Slide left"><a href="#"></a></div>');
            $(self.sliderId).after('<div class="coda-nav-right-arrow" data-dir="next" title="Slide right"><a href="#"></a></div>');
        }
        else{
            $(self.sliderId).before('<div class="coda-nav-left" data-dir="prev" title="Slide left"><a href="#">' + self.options.dynamicArrowLeftText + '</a></div>');
            $(self.sliderId).after('<div class="coda-nav-right" data-dir="next" title="Slide right"><a href="#">' + self.options.dynamicArrowRightText + '</a></div>');
        }
    },

    events: function(){
        var self = this;
        // CLick arrows
        $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('[class^=coda-nav-]').on('click', function(e){
            // These prevent clicking when in continuous mode, which would break it otherwise.
            if (!self.clickable && self.options.continuous) {return false;}
            self.setCurrent($(this).attr('class').split('-')[2]);
            if (self.options.continuous) {self.clickable = false;}
            return false;
        });
        // Click tabs
        $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('[class^=coda-nav] li').on('click', function(e){
            if (!self.clickable && self.options.continuous) {return false;}
            self.setCurrent(parseInt( $(this).attr('class').split('tab')[1], 10) - 1 );
            if (self.options.continuous) {self.clickable = false;}
            return false;
        });
        // Click cross links
        $('[data-ref*=' + (self.sliderId).split('#')[1] + ']').on('click', function(e){
            if (!self.clickable && self.options.continuous) {return false;}
            // Stop and Play controls
            if (self.options.autoSlideControls) {
                if ($(this).attr('name') === 'stop') {
                    $(this).html(self.options.autoSlideStartText).attr('name', 'start');
                    clearTimeout(self.autoslideTimeout);
                    return false;
                }
                if ($(this).attr('name') === 'start') {
                    $(this).html(self.options.autoSlideStopText).attr('name', 'stop');
                    self.setCurrent(self.currentTab + 1);
                    self.autoSlide();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            self.setCurrent( parseInt( $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1] -1, 10 ) );
            if (self.options.continuous) {self.clickable = false;}
            if (self.options.autoSlideStopWhenClicked) { clearTimeout(self.autoslideTimeout); }
            return false;
        });
        // Click to stop autoslider
        $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('*').on('click', function(e){
            // AutoSlide controls.
            if (self.options.autoSlideControls && autoSlideStopWhenClicked) {
                $('body').find('[data-ref*=' + (self.sliderId).split('#')[1] + '][name=stop]').html(self.options.autoSlideStartText);
                clearTimeout(self.autoslideTimeout);
            }
            if (!self.clickable && self.options.continuous) {
                if (self.options.autoSlideStopWhenClicked) { clearTimeout(self.autoslideTimeout); }
                return false;
            }
            if (self.options.autoSlide) {
                // Clear the timeout
                if (self.options.autoSlideStopWhenClicked) { clearTimeout(self.autoslideTimeout); }
                else {
                    self.autoSlide(clearTimeout(self.autoslideTimeout));
                    self.clickable = true;
                }
            }
            // Stops from speedy clicking for continuous sliding.
            if (self.options.continuous) {clearTimeout(self.continuousTimeout);}
        });
    },

    setCurrent: function( direction ){
        var self = this;
        if (self.clickable) {

            if (typeof direction == 'number') { self.currentTab = direction;    }
            else {
                // "left" = -1; "right" = 1;
                self.currentTab += ( ~~( direction === 'right' ) || -1 );
                // If not continuous, slide back at the last or first panel
                if (!self.options.continuous){
                    self.currentTab = (self.currentTab < 0) ? this.panelCount - 1 : (self.currentTab % this.panelCount);
                }
            }
            // This is so the height will match the current panel, ignoring the clones.
            // It also adjusts the count for the "currrent" class that's applied
            if (self.options.continuous) {
                self.panelHeightCount = self.currentTab + 1;
                if (self.currentTab === self.panelCount - 2){self.setTab = 0;}
                else if (self.currentTab === -1) {self.setTab = self.panelCount - 3;}
                else {self.setTab = self.currentTab;}
            }
            else{
                self.panelHeightCount = self.currentTab;
                self.setTab = self.currentTab;
            }
            // Add and remove current class.
            $($(self.sliderId).parent()).find('.tab' + (self.setTab + 1) + ' a:first')
                .addClass('current')
                .parent().siblings().children().removeClass('current');

            // Update Hash Tags
            if (self.options.hashLinking) {
                //console.log( ((self.$elem).find(self.options.hashTitleSelector)[self.currentTab] ));
            if (self.options.continuous) {
                if (self.currentTab === self.panelCount - 2) {
                    window.location.hash = 1;
                } else if (self.currentTab === -1) {
                    window.location.hash = self.panelCount - 2;
                } else {
                    window.location.hash = self.currentTab + 1;
                }
            } else { window.location.hash = self.currentTab + 1; }
        }

            this.transition();
        }
    },

    transition: function(){
        var self = this;
        // Adjust the height
        if (self.options.autoHeight) {
            $(self.panelContainer).parent().animate({
                'height': $($(self.panelContainer).children()[self.panelHeightCount]).height()
            }, {
                easing: self.options.autoHeightEaseFunction,
                duration: self.options.autoHeightEaseDuration,
                queue: false
                });
        }

        // Adjust the margin for continuous sliding
        if (self.options.continuous) {self.marginLeft = -(self.currentTab * self.slideWidth ) - self.slideWidth;}
        // Otherwise adjust as normal
        else {self.marginLeft = -(self.currentTab * self.slideWidth ); }
        // Animate the slider
        (self.panelContainer).animate({
            'margin-left': self.marginLeft + self.pSign
        }, {
            easing: self.options.slideEaseFunction,
            duration: self.options.slideEaseDuration,
            queue: false,
            complete: self.continuousSlide(self.options.slideEaseDuration + 50)
        });
    },

    autoSlide: function(){
        var self = this;
        // Can't set the autoslide slower than the easing ;-)
        if (self.options.autoSlideInterval < self.options.slideEaseDuration) {
            self.options.autoSlideInterval = (self.options.slideEaseDuration > self.options.autoHeightEaseDuration) ? self.options.slideEaseDuration : self.options.autoHeightEaseDuration;
        }
        if (self.options.continuous) {self.clickable = false;}
        self.autoslideTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            // Slide left or right
            self.setCurrent( self.options.autoSliderDirection );
            self.autoSlide();

        }, self.options.autoSlideInterval);
    },

    continuousSlide: function (delay){
        var self = this;

        if (self.options.continuous) {
            self.continuousTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                // If on the last panel (the clone of panel 1), set the margin to the original.
                if (self.currentTab === self.panelCount - 2){
                    $(self.panelContainer).css('margin-left', -self.slideWidth + self.pSign);
                    self.currentTab = 0;
                }
                // If on the first panel the clone of the last panel), set the margin to the original.
                else if (self.currentTab === -1){
                    $(self.panelContainer).css('margin-left', -( ((self.slideWidth * self.panelCount) - (self.slideWidth * 2))) + self.pSign );
                    self.currentTab = (self.panelCount - 3);
                }
                self.clickable = true;
            }, delay);
        }
        else{self.clickable = true;}
    }
};

$.fn.codaSlider = function( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {

        var slider = Object.create( Slider );
        slider.init( options, this );

    });
};

$.fn.codaSlider.options = {
    autoHeight: false,
    autoHeightEaseDuration: 1500,
    autoHeightEaseFunction: "easeInOutExpo",
    autoSlide: true,
    autoSliderDirection: 'right',
    autoSlideInterval: 7000,
    autoSlideControls: false,
    autoSlideStartText: 'Start',
    autoSlideStopText: 'Stop',
    autoSlideStopWhenClicked: true,
    continuous: true,
    crossLinking: true, // No longer used
    dynamicArrows: false,
    dynamicArrowsGraphical: false,
    dynamicArrowLeftText: "&#171; left",
    dynamicArrowRightText: "right &#187;",
    dynamicTabs: true,
    dynamicTabsAlign: "center",
    dynamicTabsPosition: "top",
    externalTriggerSelector: "a.xtrig", //shouldnt need any more
    firstPanelToLoad: 1,
    hashLinking: false,
    panelTitleSelector: "h2.title",
    slideEaseDuration: 1500,
    slideEaseFunction: "easeInOutExpo"
};

 })( jQuery, window, document );
```

а вот код jquery скрипта внутри html, который берет инфу из xml файла внутри html

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET", // метод передачи данных, можно пропустить - по умолчанию и так get
        url: "data.xml", // путь к файлу, который будем читать
        dataType: "xml", // тип данных, с которыми работаем
        success: function(xml) { // переменная названа xml. ее можно назвать как либо по другому
        /*
            в ответе приходит объект XML.
            чтобы добраться до необходимого узла, используем jQuery-поиск по DOM узлам
            например, var idItem = jQuery(xml).find("#item1").eq(1).attr("id");
        */
        jQuery(xml).find('lamps').each(
            function()
            {

                var id = jQuery(this).attr('id'),
                    razdel = jQuery(this).find('razdel').text(),
                    desc = jQuery(this).find('desc').text(),
                    link = jQuery(this).find('link').text(),
                    icon = jQuery(this).find('icon').text();
                jQuery('<a href="'+link+'" class="cat1"></a>').html('<div class="divimg">    <img src="'+icon+'" /></div><div class="cattext"><font class="cathead">'+razdel+'</font><p>'+desc+'</div>').appendTo('#p2-data');

            });

        }

    });

 });

</script>
```

Проблема в том что вместо 4 позиций выводится 8. Вне слайдера все нормально работает и он выводит 4 позиции.

Comment: http://iteria-group.ru/catalog.html

Comment: жесть, с трудом вниз прокрутил.

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше будет выложить не весь код слайдера и лишь ссылку на него.

Comment: В следующий раз, уважаемый @dannynyman, много думайте, прежде чем простынями постить. Авось и сами догадаетесь где ошибка анонимно зарылась.